# Aptana 3.0.6 disable annoying start-up page in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, aptana

I downloaded and installed Aptana 3.0.6 eclipse plugin (on Ubuntu 11.10) -- how do I get rid of the starting page which shows up when eclipse (finally) boots?  I have looked at all the options under Windows->Preferences and cannot find anything related.  I clearly remember it from some previous version.

Many thanks, and happy Sunday.

Answer (score 5):

You could disable it by unchecking **Aptana Portal UI** in Windows > Preferences > General > Startup and Shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows > Preferences > General > Aptana > Startup Page, check "Never display after startup"

Answer (score 0):

in Eclipse 10.7 and Aptana 2.0 the startup settings can be found in:
Window > Preferences > Aptana > Startup Page
Here you can choose to never show it again or only after an update.